# rsync hangs when syncing VirtualBox directory in expect script

Tags: expect, rsync

My expect script fails to proceed when r-syncing the VirtualBox directories.

Here is the script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f

         spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/james/Documents/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Documents/
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/james/AndroidDev/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/AndroidDev/
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/james/Android/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Android/
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/james/Videos/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Videos/ ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats /home/james/VirtualBox\ VMs/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/"VirtualBox\ VMs/" ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/james/Pictures/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Pictures ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn scp -v /home/james/.vimrc username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn scp -v /home/james/.bashrc username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn scp -v /home/james/.profile username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1

         spawn scp -v /home/james/.xsession* username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
         expect "password:"
         send "thepassword\r"
         interact
         sleep 1
```

If I change `spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/rschostag/VirtualBox\ VMs/ remote@server:/home/directory/BAK/VirtualBox` to `spawn scp -vr /home/rschostag/VirtualBox\ VMs/ remote@server:/home/directory/BAK/VirtualBox`, it works. However, I do not want to do full backup every time.

What is the best way to incrementally backup this directory or otherwise make the rsync command work properly?

Thank you!

As requested, please find the output of `expect -d script` as follows:

```
$ sudo expect -d rsync_backup
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = rsync_backup  
set argc 0
set argv0 "rsync_backup"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file rsync_backup
spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/james/Documents/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Documents/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5064}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "password:"? no
username@server password: 
expect: does "username@server password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server password:"
send: sending "thepassword\r" to { exp6 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp6 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp6 sent <sending incremental file list\r\n>
sending incremental file list
spawn id exp6 sent <Scripts/rsync.log\r\n>
Scripts/rsync.log
spawn id exp6 sent <\r          2.29K   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  >
          2.29K   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  spawn id exp6 sent <\r          5.26M 100%   78.42MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1561/3024)\r\n>
          5.26M 100%   78.42MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1561/3024)
spawn id exp6 sent <projects/JOBS/jobsearch_production/\r\n>
projects/JOBS/jobsearch_production/
spawn id exp6 sent <projects/JOBS/jobsearch_production/db.sqlite3\r\n>
projects/JOBS/jobsearch_production/db.sqlite3
spawn id exp6 sent <\r          5.41K   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  >
          5.41K   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  spawn id exp6 sent <\r          7.35M 100%   73.71MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1025/6252)\r\n>
          7.35M 100%   73.71MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1025/6252)
spawn id exp6 sent <\r\nNumber of files: 10,529 (reg: 8,419, dir: 2,096, link: 14)>

Number of files: 10,529 (reg: 8,419, dir: 2,096, link: 14)spawn id exp6 sent <\r\nNumber of created files: 0>

Number of created files: 0spawn id exp6 sent <\r\nNumber of regular files transferred: 2>

Number of regular files transferred: 2spawn id exp6 sent <\r\nTotal file size: 1.73G bytes>

Total file size: 1.73G bytesspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nTotal transferred file size: 12.61M bytes>

Total transferred file size: 12.61M bytesspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nLiteral data: 62.70K bytes>

Literal data: 62.70K bytesspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nMatched data: 12.55M bytes>

Matched data: 12.55M bytesspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nFile list size: 0>

File list size: 0spawn id exp6 sent <\r\nFile list generation time: 0.001 seconds>

File list generation time: 0.001 secondsspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nFile list transfer time: 0.000 seconds>

File list transfer time: 0.000 secondsspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nTotal bytes sent: 333.42K>

Total bytes sent: 333.42Kspawn id exp6 sent <\r\nTotal bytes received: 40.66K>

Total bytes received: 40.66Kspawn id exp6 sent <\r\n\r\n>


spawn id exp6 sent <sent 333.42K bytes  received 40.66K bytes  32.53K bytes/sec\r\ntotal size is 1.73G  speedup is 4,616.35>
sent 333.42K bytes  received 40.66K bytes  32.53K bytes/sec
total size is 1.73G  speedup is 4,616.35spawn id exp6 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp6
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/james/AndroidDev/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/AndroidDev/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5069}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "password:"? no
username@server password: 
expect: does "username@server password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server password:"
send: sending "thepassword\r" to { exp7 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp7 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp7 sent <sending incremental file list>
sending incremental file listspawn id exp7 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp7 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp7 sent <Number of files: 2,758 (reg: 2,273, dir: 485)>
Number of files: 2,758 (reg: 2,273, dir: 485)spawn id exp7 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp7 sent <Number of created files: 0>
Number of created files: 0spawn id exp7 sent <\r\nNumber of regular files transferred: 0\r\nTotal file size: 1.00G bytes>

Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 1.00G bytesspawn id exp7 sent <\r\nTotal transferred file size: 0 bytes>

Total transferred file size: 0 bytesspawn id exp7 sent <\r\nLiteral data: 0 bytes\r\nMatched data: 0 bytes>

Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytesspawn id exp7 sent <\r\nFile list size: 0\r\nFile list generation time: 0.001 seconds>

File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 secondsspawn id exp7 sent <\r\nFile list transfer time: 0.000 seconds>

File list transfer time: 0.000 secondsspawn id exp7 sent <\r\nTotal bytes sent: 74.25K\r\n>

Total bytes sent: 74.25K
spawn id exp7 sent <Total bytes received: 2.43K\r\n\r\nsent 74.25K bytes  received 2.43K bytes  30.67K bytes/sec>
Total bytes received: 2.43K

sent 74.25K bytes  received 2.43K bytes  30.67K bytes/secspawn id exp7 sent <\r\ntotal size is 1.00G  speedup is 13,102.55>

total size is 1.00G  speedup is 13,102.55spawn id exp7 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp7
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/james/Android/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Android/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5074}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp8) match glob pattern "password:"? no
username@server password: 
expect: does "username@server password: " (spawn_id exp8) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp8"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server password:"
send: sending "thepassword\r" to { exp8 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp8 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp8 sent <sending incremental file list\r\n>
sending incremental file list
spawn id exp8 sent <\r\nNumber of files: 3 (dir: 3)>

Number of files: 3 (dir: 3)spawn id exp8 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp8 sent <Number of created files: 0>
Number of created files: 0spawn id exp8 sent <\r\nNumber of regular files transferred: 0>

Number of regular files transferred: 0spawn id exp8 sent <\r\nTotal file size: 0 bytes>

Total file size: 0 bytesspawn id exp8 sent <\r\nTotal transferred file size: 0 bytes>

Total transferred file size: 0 bytesspawn id exp8 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp8 sent <Literal data: 0 bytes\r\nMatched data: 0 bytes\r\nFile list size: 0>
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0spawn id exp8 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp8 sent <File list generation time: 0.001 seconds\r\nFile list transfer time: 0.000 seconds\r\nTotal bytes sent: 83>
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 83spawn id exp8 sent <\r\nTotal bytes received: 21>

Total bytes received: 21spawn id exp8 sent <\r\n\r\n>


spawn id exp8 sent <sent 83 bytes  received 21 bytes  69.33 bytes/sec\r\ntotal size is 0  speedup is 0.00>
sent 83 bytes  received 21 bytes  69.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00spawn id exp8 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp8
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/james/Videos/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Videos/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5079}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "password:"? no
username@server password: 
expect: does "username@server password: " (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp9"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server password:"
send: sending "thepassword\r" to { exp9 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp9 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp9 sent <sending incremental file list\r\n>
sending incremental file list
spawn id exp9 sent <\r\nNumber of files: 30 (reg: 29, dir: 1)\r\nNumber of created files: 0>

Number of files: 30 (reg: 29, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0spawn id exp9 sent <\r\nNumber of regular files transferred: 0>

Number of regular files transferred: 0spawn id exp9 sent <\r\nTotal file size: 1.35G bytes>

Total file size: 1.35G bytesspawn id exp9 sent <\r\nTotal transferred file size: 0 bytes>

Total transferred file size: 0 bytesspawn id exp9 sent <\r\nLiteral data: 0 bytes>

Literal data: 0 bytesspawn id exp9 sent <\r\nMatched data: 0 bytes\r\nFile list size: 0>

Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0spawn id exp9 sent <\r\nFile list generation time: 0.001 seconds>

File list generation time: 0.001 secondsspawn id exp9 sent <\r\nFile list transfer time: 0.000 seconds>

File list transfer time: 0.000 secondsspawn id exp9 sent <\r\nTotal bytes sent: 587\r\n>

Total bytes sent: 587
spawn id exp9 sent <Total bytes received: 11\r\n\r\nsent 587 bytes  received 11 bytes  398.67 bytes/sec\r\n>
Total bytes received: 11

sent 587 bytes  received 11 bytes  398.67 bytes/sec
spawn id exp9 sent <total size is 1.35G  speedup is 2,263,533.89\r\n>
total size is 1.35G  speedup is 2,263,533.89
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp9
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/james/VirtualBox VMs/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/"VirtualBox VMs/"
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {5084}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp10) match glob pattern "password:"? no
username@server password: 
expect: does "username@server password: " (spawn_id exp10) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server password:"
send: sending "thepassword\r" to { exp10 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp10 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp10 sent <sending incremental file list\r\n>
sending incremental file list
```

This is where it hangs and does not provide an error message that I can identify.

I moved the remote VirtualBox directory and started the backup again, and it completed finally after running the backup for a few days. The total size of the backup was 71 GB. I ran it with `expect -d` which prints a very verbose output in the terminal, so that was helpful alone, because the script without -d may have looked like it was hanging only because it was not printing anything in the output. So, there was never anything wrong, I believe, other than no progress indication, which made me believe that it may not be working.

Thank you for advising me about the `expect -d` option.

Comment: use `expect eof` instead of `interact`. Also, add debug output so you can see where expect is stopping: `expect -d your_script.exp`

Comment: I ran `expect -d` and found that expect did not understand `$USER`, and I realize now that expect does not understand many built-in bash variables, such as $USER. So, I replaced that with the username directory and it is running. The output will be saved to a log file, and I will update my question with that output. Thank you!

Comment: In expect, you would reference environment variables like this: `$env(USER)`. Make sure, on the shell side, you `export` the variables you want to make available for expect.

Comment: I replaced my username with `$env(USER)`; however, this did not recognize the username. I tried with `" "` around it but that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I am curious if it is just hanging because the Windows 10 VM is 15 GB, and the VirtualBox VMs directory is 71 GB. So, it may appear to be hanging but because it is a large directory, it takes a while. I experienced this hanging on Windows 10 VM for over 2 hours before.

Comment: @glennjackman Right now, it is still hanging. Using `expect -d` and it has been hanging at `spawn id exp10 sent <sending incremental file list\r\n>
sending incremental file list` for going on 2 hours.

Comment: I moved the destination directory as a test so that it starts fresh. I amended the script to `spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy --stats /home/rschostag/VirtualBox\ VMs/ remote@server:/home/directory/BAK/VirtualBox` to `spawn scp -vr /home/rschostag/VirtualBox\ VMs/ remote@server:/home/directory/BAK/"VirtualBox\ VMs/"`, placing the double-quotes around the destination folder that has a space in between `Virtualbox` and `VMs` seems to be working.

Comment: How fast is your network. Obviously transferring a 15GB file will take a while

Comment: @glennjackman can you explain what you meant by `expect eof` instead of `interact` because I replaced `interact` in my script with `eof` and it returned an error that it did not understanding that command. Also, please answer my question so I can give you points, because all I think that was wrong was that it was not printing any output for a long time. `expect -d` helped me see the output.

Comment: Feel free to provide your own answer, I was just pointing you in a different direction.

Comment: replace `interact` with `expect eof` -- "interact" is used when you want to provide control of the spawned process back to the human user; "expect eof" means the script is still in control, just waiting for the spawned process to end.

Comment: @glennjackman please answer the question because `expect oef` worked. I would like to mark your answer as the answer, and give you points.

Comment: I don't care about points.

Answer (score 0):

@glennjackman answered my question in a comment but did not answer the question formally.

Here is the new script that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/ryan/Documents/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Documents/
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/ryan/AndroidDev/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/AndroidDev/
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/ryan/Android/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Android/
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/ryan/Videos/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Videos/ ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats /home/ryan/VirtualBox\ VMs/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/"VirtualBox\ VMs/" ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn rsync -vruEtl --progress -h --log-file=rsync.log --fuzzy  --stats  /home/ryan/Pictures/ username@server:/home/username/BAK/Pictures ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn scp -v /home/ryan/.vimrc username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn scp -v /home/ryan/.bashrc username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn scp -v /home/ryan/.profile username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1

        spawn scp -v /home/ryan/.xsession* username@server:/home/username/BAK/ ;
        expect "password:"
        send "thepassword\r"
        expect eof
        sleep 1
```